# Submitting two forms with one processing file to the database in express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have two forms in one form.hbs page but with the same process.js file to process these two forms on different occasions with two different submit buttons.

When I hit the first submit button, it should be processed inside the process.js file and sent to the database, and when I hit the submit button of the second form in the same page, it should be processed still inside the process.js file and sent to the database. The first one works, but the second one doesn't, it keeps trying to submit the content of the first form. Please how do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**forms.handlebar**

```
    {{!-- FIRST FORM - MATERIAL FORM --}}
  <div id="materials">
    <form action="/forms" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{materials._id}}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category of Material</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="matName" value=" 
                  {{materials.matName}}"
                placeholder="Material Title">
            <div class="text-danger">
                {{materials.matNameError}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" value="{{materials.desc}}"
                placeholder="Material Description">
            <div class="text-danger">
                {{materials.descError}}
            </div>
        </div>
         
       <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
          <i class="fa fa-database"></i>Submit</button>
          <a href="/material-list" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>All Material records
          </a>
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>

    
     {{!-- SECOND FORM - EQUIPMENT FORM --}}
   <div id="equipments" style="display:none">
    <form action="/forms" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{equipments._id}}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title of Equipment</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eqName" value=" 
                  {{equipments.eqName}}"
                placeholder="Equipment Title">
            <div class="text-danger">
                {{equipments.eqNameError}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input type="desc" class="form-control" name="quantity" value=" 
               {{equipments.quantity}}"
                placeholder="Quantity of Equipment">
            <div class="text-danger">
                {{equipments.quantityError}}
            </div>
        </div>
         
       <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
          <i class="fa fa-database"></i>Submit</button>
          <a href="/equipment-list" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>All Equipment records
          </a>
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
```

**router.js**

```
        //launching all forms
    router.get('/forms', MaterialController.launchForm);
    
       //posting & updating data to db
   router.post('/forms', MaterialController.createElement)
   router.post('/forms', EquipmentController.createElement);

      //getting list of existing items
   router.get('/material-list', MaterialController.Lists)
   router.get('/equipment-list', EquipmentController.Lists)

      //getting list by ids
   router.get('/:id', MaterialController.ids)
   router.get('/:id', EquipmentController.ids);

     //deleting items from db
   router.get('/delete/:id', MaterialController.delete);
   router.get('/delete/:id', EquipmentController.delete)
```

I know there's a way to use javascript to choose which button is being clicked for submission, but I really don't know how to implement this.
Please any assistance offered will be highly appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May it will be better to set "submit" action on form (as result remove  tags)

```
const elemetns = {
    equipmentsForm: document.getElementById('equipments') <== set this id to form,
    materialsForm: document.getElementById('materials') <== set this id to form
}
```

after add submit to each form

```
elemetnts.equipmentsForm.submit(e => processForm(e, elemetnts.equipmentsForm, someRoute))
elemetnts.materialsForm.submit(e => processForm(e, elemetnts.materialsForm, someRoute))
```

after it create "processForm" func

```
  fucntion processForm (e, form, route) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: route,
    data
}).done(() => console.log('success'));
}
```

here i use $.ajax. But you can use new XMLHttpRequest() constructor. Find out how create XMLHttpRequest.

so, i think, it is enought to solve your case.

Best regards!

Comment: Thank you so much @dkostreba for your answer, I appreciate it. I've tried the above solution, but its still taking me back to the first form fields. I don't know if I'm supposed to still set the form method to /forms?